# Only one LIKE pr. movie post in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

In my movie application, I'd like a user to like a movie post (I've made that functionality), but I only want them to like once pr. movie post. How can I achieve this?

Movies model:

```
const moviesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    moviesData: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', moviesSchema);
```

Movies route:

// Add like to movie

```
router.patch('/admin/like/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("POST LIKE to movie")

    try {
        await Movie.findById(req.params.id, async function (err, m) {
            if (err) next(err)
            m.likes = m.likes + 1
            await m.save();
            res.status(201).json({ message: "Added 1 like", "number_of_likes": m.likes })
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "An error has occurred", error: error });
    }
})
```

Comment: In my experience, it's often better to save each "like" as it's own unique entry in the db. The entry would map a user ID to a movie ID. The problem with simply storing a count is that at some point, you might decide you'll want to query all of the movies a user has liked, and without a mapping to go between the two, you won't be able to make such a query.

Comment: To know that a user has already liked a movie, you either have to store with the movie a list of users who have liked it or you have to store with a user which movies they've liked.  Then, in either case, you can query if they've already liked it or not.  I would guess that it may be more generally useful for other things to store with the user a list of movies they have liked - though that's really up to you.  There may even be reasons to store it both ways.

Comment: Or, you could store likes separately where each like has a user and a movie.  While that's ultimately very flexible, it may not be the fastest for common things you want to know (like how many likes for a movie or which movies has a given user liked).

Comment: create another collection and save user and movie for each like if users wants to like first query to that collection and insure user didn't like this movie if liked , add new entry and update count of like

Comment: Thanks for the comments! has anyone any code examples? That would be great